# Redirect permanent for url with question mark(?)!

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I am looking for an Apache redirect for the URL which has this form:

```
RedirectPermanent /article-111-?%C2%A0-122.html http://www.exemple.com/article-111-122.html
```

Comment: You should improve your question adding all clues necessary to give you a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(top!= self) top.location.href = self.location.href
</script>
```

it will work!